# Shared dictionaries in multiprocessing in python are not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing in python to run 4 different functions parallelly and shared a   dictionary that will store the data that i got running those functions but its not working I the value i am saving in that dictonary is not be saved
my code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    all_repo_data = manager.dict() // this is the dictionary that will save all data

    repos_data = total_repo_fetch(data, total_repos)
    fetch_repo_info(all_repo_data, repos_data, total_stars,)


    f1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = total_commit_fetch,args = (all_repo_data,))

    f2 = multiprocessing.Process(target =total_commit_user,args = (all_repo_data, Total_commits_of_user,))

    f3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=total_contributors, args=(all_repo_data,))

    f4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=fetch_language, args=(all_repo_data,))

    f1.start()
    f2.start()
    f3.start()
    f4.start()
    f2.join()
    f3.join()
    f4.join()
    f1.join()
```

fetch repo function

```
def fetch_repo_info(all_repo_data, repos_data, total_stars,):
    for repo in (repos_data):
        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])] = {}
        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['name'] = (repo)
        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['id'] = (repo['id'])
        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['stars'] = repo['stargazers_count']
        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['commits_url'] = repo['commits_url'].split("{")[0]
        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['languages'] = (repo['url'] + '/languages')
        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['contributors'] = repo['contributors_url']

        total_stars = all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['stars']+total_stars
```

error i am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\function.py", line 247, in <module>
    fetch_repo_info(all_repo_data, repos_data, total_stars,)
  File "d:\function.py", line 194, in fetch_repo_info
    total_stars = all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['stars']+total_stars
KeyError: 'stars'
```

Comment: Random guess, but you're adding a regular dict to a managed multiprocessing dict and expecting it to be shared across processes.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann can you explain a bit or point out how can i do it

Comment: It *may* be because you're not using Manager in the traditional way - i.e., as a Work Manager. Not that it has anything to do with your particular problem but do take a look at [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/concurrent.futures.html). It will make your code more manageable

Comment: @BrutusForcus can you tell me what i have done wrong

Comment: Not really because the code you've posted cannot be run/reproduced by anyone on Stackoverflow. What I can tell you though is that your error means exactly what it says - i.e., the key 'stars' is absent

Comment: @BrutusForcus but as you can see I have  just initialized the 'star' key in fetch_repo_info function just before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem:

When you create a managed dictionary, the actual implementation of that dictionary "lives" in the address space of a new process that is created by the `Multiprocessing.SyncManager` instance that is created and started when you call `multiprocessing.Manager()`. The actual value that is returned by `multiprocessor.Manager().dict()` is a reference to a special *proxy* in shared memory that is created, which can be passed to other processes. But when you invoked a method on this proxy, what is actually happening is that the proxy is sending a message to the manager server process via a socket to perform the method on the actual dictionary implementation in the server's address space.

So you can add a key/value pair to the managed dictionary where that value is a dictionary. But if you start modifying that dictionary by adding/deleting/modifying keys, since that dictionary is not a managed dictionary, you are only modifying the copy in the local address space. This can be demonstrated as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time

def worker1(d):
    d2 = {'a': 1}
    d['x'] = d2
    # Add key 'b' to d2:
    d2['b'] = 2

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Manager().dict()
    p1 = Process(target=worker1, args=(d,))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'x': {'a': 1}}
```

Note that key 'b' is not present.

To get the above code to work as you might expect, you must notify the managed dictionary that one of its key's values has been modified:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time

def worker1(d):
    d2 = {'a': 1}
    d['x'] = d2
    # Add key 'b' to d2:
    d2['b'] = 2
    # Let the managed dictionary know about the updated 'x' key:
    d['x'] = d2 # or: d.update({'x': d2})

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Manager().dict()
    p1 = Process(target=worker1, args=(d,))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'x': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

So in your code, anytime you modify a nested managed dictionary key, such as:

```py
all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['stars'] = repo['stargazers_count']
```

This needs to be:

```py
key = repo['name']
d = all_repo_data[key]
d['stars'] = repo['stargazers_count']
all_repo_data[key] = d # notify proxy
```

In general, if you have:

```py
all_repo_data[value_1][value_2] = x
```

You need to replace this with:

```py
d = all_repo_data[value_1]
d[value_2] = x
# Update the key in the managed dictionary
all_repo_data[value_1] = d
```

**Update**

You can solve your problem, simplify your code and make it much more efficient all at the same time by rewriting `fetch_repo_info`:

```py
def fetch_repo_info(all_repo_data, repos_data, total_stars):
    for repo in repos_data:
        d = {
            'name': repo,
            'id': repo['id'],
            'stars': repo['stargazers_count'],
            'commits_url': repo['commits_url'].split("{")[0],
            'languages': repo['url'] + '/languages',
            'contributors': repo['contributors_url']
        }
        all_repo_data[repo['name']] = d
        total_stars += repo['stargazers_count']
```

Comment: I want to use manager dictionary both in a multiprocessing functions and normal function so will it work on both same?

Comment: Yes, it will work exactly the same. The managed dictionary is a proxy reference in the main process that created the dictionary so the same rule applies.

Comment: can you send the correct form of these to so i can understand  properly now its bit tricky and confusing with only one example                                                                                 
        ```all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['id'] = (repo['id'])```
        ```all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['stars'] = repo['stargazers_count']```

Comment: I have updated the answer. The general case is actually very easy.

Comment: I updated the answer again. When the dictionary is nested more than two deep, it's really complicated. But that's not the case here.

Comment: is there any other easy method to pass 2d dictionary to multiprocessing functions?

Comment: If you mean is there an easier method of having a dictionary nested within another dictionary that can be shared across processes, I don't see another way **with the style of coding you have adopted.** But your entire `fetch_repo_info` function can (and should) be totally rewritten. See the updated answer.

Comment: But by passing `total_stars` as an argument and not returning it, you are only updating a value that is local to `fetch_repo_info`. So if you have `total_stars` defined globally, it will not be updated. In other words, this does not look correct.